# Merge header columns datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am trying to merge cell headers in a WPF 4.0 DataGrid. For example I have two fields in the database that are named Image1, and Image2. What I want to do is have one column header span both image columns with the text "Images", instead of what there is now, "First Image" over the Image1 column, and "Second Image" over the Image2 column. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This question is discussed here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1e414159-70f6-4be3-9be5-56e4f3278366/

Comment: Could anyone with more experience on StackExchange tell me whether this is an appropriate answer? Would a comment have been better?

Comment: In general it would be preferred that you, when linking off-site, summarize the answer/copy relevant code given there in a way that the answer can stand on its own. I cannot speak for everyone though and this is not a solid rule.

Comment: Here is me from the far future finding this answer, clicking the link and then realizing that it's broken.

Comment: Sorry about that! Nearly thirteen years later, I have absolutely no memory of this.