# Merge Grid column Header in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a wpf Grid, i want to merge the two Column Header.I have tried using the below code the problem here is the column spawn to 2 but in the cell is one that why the for each column grid line is not visible.Can any body answer the better solution to achieve this

```
<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
      <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Missing from FISAP Summary Part II Section F"/>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="A" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="C"  Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="D"  Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Grid>
   </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
   <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition/>
               <ColumnDefinition/>
               <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=A}" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=C}" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=D}" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[image]

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781403/wpf-datagrid-super-header-for-multiple-columns?rq=1. Do you want the same way as in the question

Comment: yes, but the answer is not correct.In my case it is not working what i am expected.

Comment: not the answer just clarification for the question

Comment: ok,Do you have any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446684/merge-header-columns-datagrid-wpf, I am not sure about multi line columns. I know Xceed supports that but it will be some work with WPF datagrid